# openpyxl generates broken workbook

Tags: python, excel, xlsx, openpyxl

I am using openpyxl (2.3.5). 
When I create a new workbook and open it with Microsoft Excel, it pops up an error saying:

> "We found a problem with some content in 'pourquoi.xlsx'. Do you want us to try to recover as much as we can? If you trust the source of this workbook, Click Yes"

When I click 'Yes', my file is repaired.

Here is the simple code :

```
>>> import openpyxl                  
>>> wb = openpyxl.Workbook()                     
>>> wb.save('pourquoi.xlsx')
```

Comment: Did you really hit the issue with only 3 lines of code? Here is what I tried to answer, for your reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57982349/writing-dataframes-to-multiple-sheets-in-existing-excel-file-get-we-found-prob

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, these error messages are often not very helpful. Which version of Excel are you using? It's worth noting that *Excel 2007* is no longer supported.

Bugs should be reported using the [bug tracker](https://bitbucket.org/openpyxl/openpyxl/issues)

For more information you need to look more closely at the file itself, using something like the MS OOXML Productivity Tool. All the files that openpyxl produces are valid OOXML files but Excel can still take exception to valid files.

Comment: Yes I am using _Excel 2007_ and the problem does not show with libreoffice.
Thank you.

Comment: Excel 2007 was released before the OOXML standard was released and does not implement it fully. I cannot test it and it is no longer supported by Microsoft either (partly for this reason).