# Writing dataframes to multiple sheets in existing Excel file. Get 'We Found Problem with some content in X.xlsx' when opening excel file

Tags: excel, pandas, openpyxl

I'm creating a few dfs based on existing excel files. I'm then writing each of those dfs to their own separate sheet in a different (existing excel) file. Script executes fine, but when I open the excel file the dfs were written to I get the following error msg: "We found a problem with some content in 'X.xlsx'...

I tried this not using openpyxl as several answers on similar posts indicated you didn't have to use openpyxl; however, pandas docs indicate you need to use openpyxl if writing to .xlsx.

```
import pandas as pd
from openpyxl import load_workbook

df_complete = pd.read_excel('completed_contracts_2019.xlsx', 
index_col=None)
df_wip_out = pd.read_excel('wip19.xlsx', index_col=None)
df_in = pd.read_excel('wip_18_to_19.xlsx', index_col=None)

with pd.ExcelWriter('Final_Template.xlsx', engine='openpyxl') as writer:
    writer.book = load_workbook('Final_Template.xlsx')
    df_complete.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='complete', index=False)
    df_wip_out.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='wipout', index=False)
    df_in.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='wipin', index=False)
```

I expect to open the excel file without getting the error.

Comment: Are you able to save it to a new excel file in different sheets, instead of opening an existing one? (Just to discard issues with the df to excel formatting)

Comment: You have to use openpyxl if you want to write into an existing file. But, basically you can do everything you want to do with openpyxl here. No need for pandas at all. Just read the workbooks using read-only mode.

Comment: @CeliusStingher I can save to new excel file, but I get same error when opening new excel file.

Comment: @CharlieClark
The problem was the file I was writing to. Some sheets had tables that were connected to external sources. Once I 'unlinked' those, the script worked & I didn't get the error when I opened the file the script wrote to.

Comment: openpyxl will remove those links with the `keep_links=False` parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Hit the same issue with openpyxl, but actually it might not be the problem of openpyxl.

Based on my experience, after I got a pop window with "Alert We found a problem with some content in......". Just look into what was the error, and finally found that, in Excel if the data format is "General", you cannot input the string starts with "==", otherwise Excel will deem it as a syntax error. But if the data format is "Text", there will be no problem.

Two solution:
1) If you are sure some of the string starts with "==", and it is not that necessary in your case, you might have to change the first "=" or insert another character at the beginning. Then write it into xls file with openpyxl. This is what I applied.
2) Or you may use openpyxl set the data format of cell (might be "number_format") as "Text". I didn't successfully try this way, because after manually setting a cell data format as "Text", read its "number_format" with openpyxl, got the value of "@"(not "Text"). But when I set "number_format" to "@" with openpyxl, then wrote "==" into it, it still hit the issue.

Besides "==", not sure if any other string will also be deemed as a syntax error by Excel. Anyway, if you happen to hit the issue due to "==", you can try the first solution as a workaround.